# php mail get wordpress values

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I`m using wordpress and I have created a register form, and when user clicks on "register" the message comes to email, its right.

But messages come like this| From: Wordpress , subject, [portal name] Your username and password info.

Im using this code:

```
        $to = 'my@mail';
        $subject = 'Thank You for regiter';
        $message = "some texr";
        $headers = 'From: My Portal' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: my@portalemail.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Now my question is, why messages when it comes to email comes with value from wordpress. Can somebody help me how to fix it /

Comment: $Headers[] = 'From: My Portal <admin@portal.com>';
$Headers[] = 'Reply-To: my@portalemail.com'; $Headers[] = 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); use this for header and check it work or not.

Comment: Its works, but the name of email is " CGI Mailer " . After that come and one email from wordpress by default.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right format for FROM header `From: My Portal <my@portalemail.com>` and I don't see any reason to use `REPLY-TO`

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type' );

$to = 'aaa@example.com';
$subject = 'Thank You for regiter';
$message = "some texr";
$headers = 'From: My Portal <my@portalemail.com>' . "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 
$email_html = '<p>This is message body<p>';
wp_mail( $to, $subject, $email_html , $headers);

// Reset content-type to avoid conflicts -- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23578
remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type' );
```

Comment: The same problem. I have tested it but the same, email comes with values  from wordpres, by default.